# eulerian bipartite complete graph

Tags: graph-theory

I must find out for what values of n and m the complete bipartite graph K(n,m) is eulerian.Can you give me some sugestions or hints to where to start ?I know the definitions but I don't know where to begin to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** A connected graph is Eulerian if and only if every vertex has what property?

Comment: every vertex has even degree

Comment: @EmilGrigore Not the same degree--rather, if and only if every vertex has even degree.

Comment: so the number of edges must be even

Comment: @EmilGrigore Yes, that's true--but is that enough?

Comment: well every vertex from K has the same number of edges as the number of  vertexes in the opposed set of vertexes.So for example:if one set contains 1,2 and another set contains 3,4,5,6,the vertexes 1,2 will have each 4 edges and the vertexes 3,4,5,6 will each have 2 vertexes.For it to be an eulerian graph,also the sets of vertexes needs to contain an even number of vertexes.

Comment: @EmilGrigore Yes, you've got it.

Comment: yeey.Thank you.Wasn't so hard.